# How is the law of conservation of energy satisfied in a photoelectric cell?

Tags: energy-conservation, photoelectric-effect

In a battery-driven circuit, the current produced is of such a value that the power delivered by the battery (VI) is equal to the power dissipated in the resistance (I^2*R). If the resistance changes, the current also changes, and the energy balance is maintained. But in a photoelectric cell the current depends on the incident optical energy, not on the resistance in the circuit. So how is energy balance achieved in this situation?

Comment: Which type of photocell are you asking about?  Is the photocell changing resistance or is it a source of emf?

Comment: @Farcher It is a source of emf with no external voltage source.

Comment: It is not true, that the current does not depend on the resistance in the circuit. it depends on the resistance, but the inner resistance of a photocell depends on the iincident energy, but also conventional batteries has an inner resistance, and the current depends on both, inner and outer resistance.

Comment: @trula Does the photocurrent depend on the load resistance or the intensity of the incident light?

Comment: Are you asking about a *photoresistor*? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor

Answer (score 0):

> in a photoelectric cell the current depends on the incident optical energy, not on the resistance in the circuit. So how is energy balance achieved in this situation?

Actually, this is incorrect. The so-called short circuit current depends on the incident optical energy, but since a short circuit voltage is zero the power is also zero. Similarly, the open circuit voltage is another characteristic of the photovoltaic cell, and since an open circuit current is zero the power is also zero.

The power drawn from a photovoltaic cell depends strongly on the load resistance. There is one specific load resistance where the power is maximized. For that resistance the voltage is just a little less than the open circuit voltage and the current is just a little less than the short circuit current. Any larger or smaller resistance will reduce the power delivered from the photovoltaic cell

Comment: To clarify, I am talking of photoelectric cells, not photovoltaic ones. The incident optical beam produces a photocurrent whose value depends on the intensity of the optical beam. In this situation, no matter what resistance is used as the load resistance, the current will be the same.

Comment: @terahertz photoelectric cells and photovoltaic cells are the same thing. The photoelectric effect (ejection of carriers from a material into space due to light) is similar to but not as useful as the photovoltaic effect (transport of carriers over a barrier within a material due to light) and they both have a "current proportional to light" quality. Due to the similarity (and historical reasons? not sure) the cells go by either name.

Comment: @terahertz a photovoltaic cell is a type of photoelectric cell, the type most relevant to the question which explicitly discussed a photoelectric cell in the context of a power source like a battery. Perhaps you can clarify your question with a direct link to the specific type of device you are asking about if it is indeed something other than a photovoltaic cell. In any case, the answer should work with only superficial modifications